# выдает ClassNotFoundException если запускать через cmd.exe

Tags: java

Выдает: `ClassNotFoundException`, если запускать через `cmd.exe`, хотя если через *Eclipse* все норм. В чём проблема?

Перерыл все сайты, не понимаю в чем проблема(я уже все пути в `CLASSPATH` писал).

Если кто шарит помогите - я готов на *TeamViewer*.

Comment: очевидно надо добавить в вопрос текст команды на запуск, которая не работает

Comment: java test.example - где test - это package,а example - имя класса

Comment: И на какой Class ругается? В текст ошибки должна быть об этом информация

Comment: ругается как раз на example.class(внутри system.out.println("helloworld"));
ClassNotFoundException - типо он не может загрузить классы которые нужны для компиляции главного класса example.class(типо он не нашел нужные классы в CLASSPATH)

Comment: а в командной строке запускаете из директории где файл джава находится? В cmd заходите в директорию с файлом и сначала "javac file.java", потом "java file"

Comment: @AliceMagic так точно!ооой,т.е. где файл .class находится,оттуда

Comment: так зачем писать пакет? нужно зайти прямо в директорию пакета и в ней работать без указания пакета... сначала javac example.java (именно в этой директории создастся файл example.class) потом java example

Comment: при компиляции эклипс создает файл байт-кода в папке bin... можно прямо в нее зайти и запустить сразу java example

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class example
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: example

все равно он не может найти класс(((

Comment: тогда не знаю... отпшитесь когда решите проблему.. даже интересно)

Comment: боюсь я сюда написал от отчаяния,уж слишком много времени потратил шоб решить эту ерунду

Comment: Давайте еще раз... у вас уже есть файл example.class (ну, раз в эклипсе запускали без проблем, значит есть). Дальше. В папке с проектом есть папка bin. В ней есть папка test (пакет). В этой папке должен лежать файл example.class... Убедились, что он там есть и скопировали из адресной строки полный путь <бла-бла-бла>.bin.test

Comment: Затем, в командной строке пишем cd <бла-бла-бла>.bin.test

Comment: Попадаем в нужную нам директорию. Можно проверить как работают прописанные пути... набираем команду java -version и если получаем описание версии, значит все в порядке и нам осталось только ввести команду java example

Comment: программа должна отработать как положено